# Using Eloquent join results in incorrect id results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query but as a result of the join the id field is completely mixed up. The Phone id for example is overwritten by the Manufacturer id.

```
 $phones = \App\Phone::
        join('phone_manufacturers', 'phones.phone_manufacturers_id', '=', 'phone_manufacturers.id')
        ->orderBy('phone_manufacturers.manufacturer_name')
        ->paginate(20);
```

How can I set an alias so that when I call phone->id it produces the correct results? I have tried using "With" instead but we then get issues with ordering the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the issue of the `id` being overlapped by the joined table field by specifying the select.

```php
 $phones = \App\Phone::select('phones.*')
    ->join('phone_manufacturers', 'phones.phone_manufacturers_id', '=', 'phone_manufacturers.id')
    ->orderBy('phone_manufacturers.manufacturer_name')
    ->paginate(20);
```

If you need the field in `phone_manufacturers` then use the relation.

Comment: Thanks this seems to have solved the issues I was trying "phone_manufacturers.*" in the select with no luck.